# How to call a non-member, non-static function from inside a member function in c++

Tags: c++, cmake

I have a file `foo.h` inside which, I have a function prototype as follows

```
int foobar(int a);
```

Its definition is inside `foo.cpp`

```
int foobar(int a){
    return a + 10;
}
```

I have another file `moo.cpp` when I have the definition of `demo` class members, and I want to call the `foobar` function from inside of one of the member functions like this:

```
demo::random(int x){
    y = foobar(x);
}
```

However, it gives me a linker error `undefined reference`. I have tried other solutions with a scope resolution operator but it isn't working and I couldn't find any other similar question.

Edit 1: Here is the full error message.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "foobar(int)", referenced from:
      demo::random(int) in libdemo.a(demo.cpp.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [test_moo] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/test_moo.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Edit 2: CMake code to compile and link the code.

```
FILE(GLOB PK_SOURCES "src/*" "app/*")
ADD_LIBRARY(moo STATIC ${PK_SOURCES})

TARGET_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(moo PUBLIC ${PK_SOURCES})

FILE(GLOB SOURCES_DEMO "app/moo.cpp")
ADD_EXECUTABLE(test_demo ${SOURCES_DEMO})
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(test_demo moo ${PLATFORM_LINKER_FLAGS})
```

Edit 3: 
My main function is inside `moo.cpp`. The other two files are inside `src` directory.

Edit 4:
Added CMake tag because possibly that is the problem.

Edit 5: I changed my make file to this and it fixed the problem. Please suggest to me how should I end this thread.

```
FILE(GLOB PK_SOURCES "src/*" "app/*")
ADD_LIBRARY(moo STATIC ${PK_SOURCES})

TARGET_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(moo PUBLIC ${PK_SOURCES})

FILE(GLOB SOURCES_DEMO "app/main.cpp")
ADD_EXECUTABLE(test_moo ${SOURCES_DEMO})
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(test_moo moo ${PLATFORM_LINKER_FLAGS})
```

Comment: This should be fine. Are you compiling both cpp files? And make sure `moo.cpp` includes `foo.h`.

Comment: @cigien yes I am.. I am using CMake and I have used `*` wildcard to compile all the cpp files in that directory

Comment: Your code should work fine as written, must be specific to how you are compiling/linking

Comment: Remember to link all your object files to the final executable.

Comment: Can you paste the *full* error message - that may give us a clue as to where the linker *thinks* the definition should be?

Comment: @CoryKramer I just noticed that I am getting the same error even after calling it from outside the member function.

Comment: Could you please show us how you are compiling and *especially* linking your code?

Comment: @AdrianMole I have pasted the full error message.

Comment: @molecule It's not the code that is at fault, it's how you are building your code. An undefined reference means that you aren't linking with the file containing the function definition (i.e. `foo.o`).

Comment: I have added the cmake code which shows how I am linking them.

Comment: @anatolyg checking.

Comment: From that CMake config it looks like you're compiling moo.cpp twice (in both libmoo and test_demo) which would be a violation of the One Definition Rule.  Your CMake config doesn't actually seem to match the linker output though.  A [mcve] would help this question a lot.

Comment: Also, `TARGET_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` call is invalid -- you feed it w/ sources instead of path(s).

Comment: … and for the God sake: please do not use file glob for getting sources! Use explicit lists!

Comment: @zaufi thank you for your suggestions. I am new to cmake. I will make the necessary changes.

Comment: Also, to pass the linker options there is the `target_link_options` command.